# Perfectly emulate nullptr

Tags: c++, null, c++11, nullptr

I got tired of waiting for compiler support of `nullptr` ([gcc 4.6 does](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html) but it's so new few distributions support it).

So as a stop gap until `nullptr` is fully supported I decided to emulate it.  There are two examples of emulation: one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419800/can-nullptr-be-emulated-in-gcc), and one from [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/nullptr#Solution_and_Sample_Code).

Of note, neither implementation mentions an `operator ==`.  However, without one, the following code [will not compile](http://ideone.com/IEeAX).

```
int* ptr = nullptr;
assert( ptr == nullptr ); // error here: missing operator ==
```

Is this `operator ==` error a compiler bug?
Is `operator ==` (and `!=`, `<`, `<=`, etc) needed to more perfectly emulate `nullptr`?
What else is different between an emulated `nullptr` and the real deal?

Comment: Why would you do this instead of `assert(ptr);` in the first place?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: That's not true. `nullptr` has to be part of the Standard because it only has value when everybody uses the same null pointer type- `std::nullptr_t`. If everyone implemented their own null pointer, how would you write a function that would accept a null pointer? You don't know what the null pointer type is.

Comment: @ildjarn: I used an assertion to clean up the code.  My actual example was `std::remove( v.begin(), v.end(), nullptr );` which uses the equality operator.  And the reason I wont just use `std::remove_if` is I don't want to. I want it to just work like the real `nullptr`.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't think about implications within the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compiled it with C++0x compiler that failed for unknown reason. It [compiles fine in C++03](http://ideone.com/rIlsC).

Comment: So, back to my original question.  Is this error an effect of new c++0x language rules? Or is it a bug that was introduced into gcc when the other c++0x features were added?

Comment: @deft_code: 1) your code is invalid C++0x because it uses the keyword nullptr. 2) I'm 90% sure it's a GCC bug 3) there already was a [similar bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33990).

Comment: Great find with that bug.  My [exact error case](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33990#c4) is listed in the comments.  In response to point 1 I've gotta say _no duh!_  It's obviously invalid in a fully compliant c++0x compiler.  gcc 4.5 isn't fully compliant yet, and hence my need to emulate a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should implement such a thing. I am, however, surprised that the implicit conversion operators aren't kicking in and allowing you to compare without providing an explicit operator.

```
template<typename T> bool operator==(T* ptr, nullptr_t null) {
    return ptr == 0;
}
template<typename C, typename R> bool operator==(R C::* ptr, nullptr_t null) {
    return ptr == 0;
}
// And the reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually mentioned in the official proposal from your first example reference:

> Experiments with several popular
>   existing compilers show that it
>   generates poor and/or misleading
>   compiler diagnostics for several of
>   the common use cases described in
>   section 2. (Examples include: “no
>   conversion from „const ‟ to „int‟”;
>   “no suitable conversion function from „const class ‟ to „int‟
>   exists”; “a template argument may not reference an unnamed type”; “no
>   operator „==‟ matches these operands, operand types are: int == const class
>   ”.) We believe that compilers will still need to add
>   special knowledge of nullptr in order
>   to provide quality diagnos- tics for
>   common use cases.

So you should fill this gap yourself if the compiler doesn't yet.

Comment: That poor compiler diagnostics discussion is in reference to an unnamed `nullptr` type.  However, the standards committee decided that `nullptr` would have the type `nullptr_t`.  All of those cryptic error messages get a lot better when the `nullptr` class is named `nullptr_t`.