# How to define nullptr for supporting both C++03 and C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03, nullptr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Backporting” nullptr to C++-pre-C++0x programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747005/backporting-nullptr-to-c-pre-c0x-programs)

How to define `nullptr` for supporting both C++03 and C++11?

Does below code is compiled with both C++03 and C++11 compiles without change the meaning of nullptr in C++11 compiler?

```
#include <cstddef>

#if !defined(nullptr)
#define nullptr NULL
#endif
```

Comment: Is it correct? No, not really. If `NULL` were equivalent to `nullptr`, there'd have been no reason to introduce the feature in the first place. What are you asking us? Whether your code will *compile*?

Comment: Check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747005/backporting-nullptr-to-c-pre-c0x-programs

Comment: `defined(nullptr)` will fail, because `nullptr` is a keyword, not a define.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In C++11, `nullptr` is of type `nullptr_t`. One of its big advantages compared to `NULL` (or to `0` would say Bjarne since he does not like macros) is that between these two functions:

```
void foo(char*);
void foo(int);
```

`foo(nullptr)` will call the `char*` overload but `foo(NULL)` will call the `int` overload. So your solution may work in most of the cases, but you may have errors with functions overload.

Comment: Certainly not the *only* advantage. You can overload on `nullptr_t` too, and that is quite useful.

Comment: Template argument deduction deduces `nullptr_t` for `nullptr` and `int` for `NULL`.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK you cannot automate *from within the code* the detection of `nullptr` support.

In practice you can read that as “impossible”, it’s a pretty strong “AFAIK”.

The thing to do is therefore to use compiler-specific code and/or build command. For example, in each relevant source add a

```
#include <cpp/nullptr.h>
```

and in the build command adjust the include path so that for compiler with `nullptr` support, this picks up an empty header, while for an old compiler that lacks `nullptr`, it picks up a header that defines it à la Meyers (say).

And then test very thoroughly!

I call the general concept of having multiple versions of a header, with just one selected by the build command, a **virtual header**. It is possible to build a lot of machinery around that, including conventions that only make sense in a more general case. Happily it’s not necessary for this particular case, but perhaps worth to be aware of.

Summing up: making C++ source code do things magically is not the way to go here. Adding a bit of help at the build level seems about right. :-)

Comment: "AFAIK you cannot automate from within the code the detection of nullptr support" at least, not in a way that covers non-conforming compilers, which in practice is approximately all of them. On conforming compilers you could, since a C++03 compiler is guaranteed not to support `nullptr` as a keyword, while a C++11 compiler is guaranteed to have it. So all you need to do is check which.