# How do I reliably detect support for nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to backport nullptr to a cross platform library we have, but I'm having trouble getting a reliable check of nullptr support.

Initially I had this:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L || (__cplusplus < 200000 && __cplusplus >= 199711L)
    // nullptr should be ok
#else
    // Too old
#endif
```

But then I discovered that compiling a program that just printed out the value of __cplusplus produced unexpected results.

One blog post claimed 199711L was a value that MS compilers use to indicate partial support for C++11.  But I notice g++ 5.4 produces that value by default.  Until you expressly tell it to use compile with -std=c++11.
But then if you tell it the standard is c++98 the value 199711 is still shown.  That doesn't sound right to me. So that's not a good check!

Then I saw [someone doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496824/how-to-define-nullptr-for-supporting-both-c03-and-c11) with an answer that claimed it may work.  Well it doesn't.

```
#if !defined(nullptr)
#endif
```

But I'm not sure you can do that.  So I tested it like this:

```
#if defined(nullptr)
#error "null ptr defined"
#endif
```

Guess what?  that doesn't print out the error when nullptr is actually available.  So that doesn't at all.

How do I detect nullptr or compiler version under linux/windows and OSX (clang)/ android.

Comment: If it's not available, your code that uses it won't compile. That seems like a pretty straightforward indicator to me. And why do you think you need to (or can) "backport" it?

Comment: Look at Boost.Config's `BOOST_NO_CXX11_NULLPTR` macro. Either use Boost.Config or duplicate the equivalent logic they use to determine this.

Comment: @Matt have you tried a typetrait checking for nullptr_t? sth like std::is_same or sth like that.

Comment: Why do you want to use `nullptr` with old compilers?  It's a nice touch, but `NULL` is almost as good.

Comment: Typical XY problem. Just use `NULL` until you don't have to support legacy compilers.

Comment: Old compiler will map `NULL` to `0`, compiler that supports `nullptr` can map `NULL` to `nullptr`. (Although not all of them do).

Comment: @RustyX - this all came about due to someone defining null to be NULL in a library we use to save his pinky. And then clashing with other libs.  So we decided to switch to nullptr to make things clear.  Can o' worms!

Comment: 199711L is the correct value for compliance to the 1998 or 2003 specs, and has nothing to do with "partial C++11 support".

Comment: @NeilButterworth - not really a backport, it's just that we had an inhouse library developed over many years that used "null"... because the main dev didn't like using his pinky to write NULL.  It seems null was clashing with other libs for other dev's so we thought time to fix it, lets switch to nullptr.  But this turned out to be a little more difficult than first thought.  defining nullptr to 0 is acceptable for us.  The fancy class based one produced more problems than it solved.  0 is fine.

Comment: @matt that last edit should be an answer instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- If you're using Boost, [Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__11_features_not_supported) provides the `BOOST_NO_CXX11_NULLPTR` macro.

  Boost implements this by defining it for each compiler-version-combo that doesn't support it, so you cannot easily duplicate the functionality.
- If you're using CMake, you can use [compiler feature detection](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#) (specifically `cxx_nullptr`) to conditionally define a macro.

`#if !defined(nullptr)` doesn't work because `nullptr` is not a macro.

Comment: regarding #if !defined(nullptr), that's what I thought too but so many people were posting answers to a question that had implemented the check that way reinforcing it as correct.  So I began to doubt what I assumed was true.  That's for confirming my first thought.

Comment: @Matt have you tried a typetrait checking for nullptr_t? sth like std::is_same or sth like that.

Comment: Doesn't Boost build this configuration when you install the library? So, unless you have a complete list of supported compilers or some external build tool to test for language features, this solution can't be used when distributing a header only library?

Comment: So we aren't using boost and I can't included boost headers in this thing, so what I ended up doing was pulling out the boost library and extracting the needed parts.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the hints to the boost library this is what I ended up with. I'm sure I'm not the only one who wants this.

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#  define GCC_VERSION (__GNUC__ * 10000 + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100 + __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)
#  if defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__) || (__cplusplus >= 201103L)
#    define GCC_CXX11
#  endif
#  if (GCC_VERSION < 40600) || !defined(GCC_CXX11)
#    define NO_CXX11_NULLPTR
#  endif
#endif

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#  if (_MSC_VER < 1600)
#    define NO_CXX11_NULLPTR
#  endif
#endif

#if defined(__clang__)
#  if !__has_feature(cxx_nullptr)
#    define NO_CXX11_NULLPTR
#  endif
#endif

#if defined(NO_CXX11_NULLPTR)
#  pragma message("Defining nullptr")
#  define nullptr 0
#endif
```